# Can I use a 240v baseboard heater wires for a 230v outlet receptacle?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, heater, baseboard

[image]I have an old Intertherm 240v hard-wired baseboard heater and would like to take the wiring and convert it into a 230v outlet instead. The heater is connected to 3 wires, white, black, and a ground. One of the live wires is also connected to a thermostat. I am hoping I can keep the thermostat at a very high temperature to ensure there is no disconnection, and use the white/black/ground wired to the baseboard heater for the 230v outlet. Would this be possible?

[image]

Comment: What is the rating of the breaker protecting the circuit? Are there any other loads on that circuit?

Comment: The white wire should be re-marked with tape to be either red or black.

Comment: White wire is a hot/live wire, not neutral as what white usually is.  These days you will be limited on what you plug into it, older dryers, welders, heaters, most other stuff need 4 wire outlets(2 hot, neutral, ground).

Comment: What Country, State or Province are you in?

Comment: What are you trying to plug into this receptacle?

Answer (score 1):

If your new outlet is just for straight 230(240) Volt and a ground then you'll be OK provided the breaker and wire size will handle the load of whatever you're going to plug into the outlet. Since the white wire is hot, it should be marked with black (usually) electrical tape (in the USA). If your outlet will need a neutral, then this wiring won't work.

Keeping the thermostat in the wiring isn't a good idea. Just splice the wires through.